# How to troubleshoot network connection issue when a single website won't load?

Tags: windows-8, router, internet, dns

I have a router which runs fine for all websites except for one in particular, that one website works sort of, it loads but no images show and the CSS sometimes doesn't load.

I have already tried running ipconfic/flushdns and the website runs fine through proxies.

What steps can I take to find the root cause of the issue?

Comment: You sure the problem isn't with the website itself? I can't think of ANYTHING on your end that would cause this unless they are using external domains to loading their content.  If thats the case then this is a pure internet provider filtering problem.

Comment: Definitely not the website, I tried accessing it through a mobile internet connection and had friends visit it and it ran fine. On computesr connecting through the router which hsa the issue the website sort of loads but no images show, it's a really strange issue.